# One KONICA MINOLTA printer reset to defaults settings on each reboot - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer

I have a problem with the KONICA MINOLTA 224e printer driver for Windows 7 pro 64 bit.

When a user changes the printer settings from the control panel, for example switching from color to mono, the settings are back to defaults when we reopen the printer settings.

The problem is only with this driver. Drivers for other KONICA and other brands do not exhibit the problem.
The problem is for all our Windows 7. Not with Windows XP 32 bit / 8.1 64 bit / 2012 R2.
We only have Windows 7 pro in 64 bit flavour, so I don't know if 32 bit have the same problem.
Our Windows 7 are from different origins: some are installed by hand, and most were preinstalled by HP/Lenovo/whatever.

I use the official driver, latest version from the official KONICA website.

The problem occur for regular users and administrators.

Temporary workaround: select another driver for this printer, then revert back to the correct driver. The settings are now modifiable **until reboot** (logoff+login is ok. Only reboot reset to the undesired behaviour). Just after reboot the registry values are ok, but revert back to defaults as soon as we use the printer or open the settings.

Even writting the desired values into registry to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\DevModes2\xx_Printer_Name_xx` does not enforce the settings, because as soon as we use the printer or open the settings, everything is back to default values.
So I think another value in registry should be written to, but I don't know which one.

My Google searches returned nothing related to my problem.

Anyone have suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Konica BizHub C224e you must use the C554 driver.
Don't ask me why, only this one works correctly.